# How to interpret blk_update_request: critical medium error?

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

I am getting this error message every now and then from one drive:

```
blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdf, sector 4820053408 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x1000 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
```

The output from `smartctl -A /dev/sdf` is:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-125-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   079   064   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       83137091
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   081   080   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       41
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1928
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   078   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       67131684
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   085   085   000    Old_age   Always       -       13977
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       41
 18 Unknown_Attribute       0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   060   051   040    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 28/48)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       8017
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   040   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (0 20 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   079   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       83137091
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       775 (195 33 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       54849800560
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       73600182478
```

I am not sure how to read the output from smartctl. Is this drive bad? What numbers am I looking for when deciding if a drive is bad? The disk is a 8TB seagate ironwolf.

Thank you for your help!